# Probability of $k$ 100-sides die tosses yield an average $\le 10$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

> Probability of $k$ 100-sides die tosses yield an average $\le 10$?

I've a complete weighted graph with edge weights $\le 100$. I want to know the probability of choosing a random path of length $k$ of weight $\le 10k$.

Since any valid path of length $k$ and weight $\le10k$ must satisfy the mean of edge weights $\le10$, so computing the probability above solves the problem.

Could someone help out a computer science student?

Comment: you could approximate with normal distribution and central limit theorem

Comment: Would you give a formula or an approximation? It is a long time since I've studied probability theory.

Comment: For each die, are the values $1,2,3,4,\ldots, 100$ equally likely? Are the dice independent?

Comment: @Henry - yes and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would expect this probability to fall quickly with $n$ dice, as the mean of the sum is is $50.5n$ and the standard deviation about $28.866\sqrt{n}$, so a sum of $10n$ or less becomes highly improbable for large $n$

As far as I can tell, the probabilities fall at a rate close to exponential and are about

```
n   prob <= 10n

1   0.1
2   0.019
3   0.00406
4   0.0009139
5   0.000211876
6   0.000050064
7   0.000011988
8   0.000002899
9   0.000000706
10  0.000000173
11  0.000000043
12  0.000000011
13  0.000000003
14  0.000000001
```

Comment: There is exponential decay here.  This follows from large deviations theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory#Large_deviations_for_sums_of_independent_random_variables

Comment: @MichaelLugo  Empirically it seems to be close to something like the form $\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}} \exp(-bn)$  where $a$ might be close to something like $0.42$ and $b$ close to something like $1.35437$.